# C compile error

Tags: c

I get the following error when compiling and the functions logged as errors are #include modules

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "_setup_gps", referenced from:
>     _setupgps in cc5V40n0.o
>    "_gps_navigation", referenced from:
>     _setupgpsnavigation in cc5V40n0.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> ```

What does this mean? I thought it is because of duplicate main functions, but I don't see any other main functions that this one

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    nav_run_gps_system();
    return 0;
}
```

I then create 2 threads using the functions mentioned in the error log. I put them in a wrapper so I can pass them to the Posix thread create function.

```
void *setupgps(void *ptr)
{
    setup_gps(UNO,57600);
}

void *setupgpsnavigation(void *ptr)
{
    struct point Destination = {-2,5742.307,1156.002};
    gps_navigation(Destination);
}


gpsSetupThreadResult = pthread_create(&gpsSetupThread, NULL, setupgps, (void*) message2);
gpsNavigationThreadResult = pthread_create(&gpsNavigationThread, NULL, setupgpsnavigation, (void*) message3);
```

Comment: That's a link error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Why did you think it has anything to do with duplicate entrypoints?

Answer (score 4):

You left the library that defines `nav_run_gps_system()` and `setupgps()` for x86_64 out of the linker path.

Comment: I never wrote these functions, I only #include them and was told just to compile using the math library -lm and I added it to my original compile command as so gcc nav_corelogic.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lm -o logic is the error with the way I structure the command?

Comment: The GPS functions are not in the XML2, M or C libraries; you need to find out which library they are in.

Comment: Its because the gps code it running on an Arduino Uno and the logic code is running on a panda board

Comment: @Helium3: If your target system is an Arduino, there's no reason you should be trying to link to x86_64 objects. Are you sure you have your cross-compiler environment set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create that functions? I guess not. It seems by the error that those functions doesn't exist for x86 computers, maybe if you compile in a amd64 you've got better luck :P

Edit: So if you are ina 64 bit computer... it has to be something with ld, check the compiling parameters of gcc or whatever you are using

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the libraries you're linking are not for `x86_64`. Try to find the correct dependencies to use.

Really, you're probably going to have to find a mailing list for the specific library and ask the people who develop it.

Comment: ah f&%K, Its for the code that is compiling onto an Arduino UNO. thanks :)